# Conditional formatting comparing tables for missing rows and/or changes

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm being dumb here. I don't know what I'm forgetting.

I have two tables on two sheets with similar structures. I would like to have the following conditional formatting rules: -

- By matching on the first three columns, highlight cells in those three columns in Sheet1.Table1 that do not exist in Sheet2.Table2.
- By matching on the first three columns, highlight cells in column four in Sheet1.Table1 that has a different value to that in Sheet2.Table2. The row must be in both tables.

The tables are sorted differently so I can't do a simple cell=cell comparison. I tried using the MATCH function, i.e. MATCH(blah)=0, but that didn't seem to do anything. I will eventually like to do this in VBA, but for now I just want to get the formulas correct and then I can write the code.

Basic example data below: -

- Following formatting rule 1 then the cells of Table1 in rows 3 & 4 within Column1:Column3 would be highlighted.
- Following formatting rule 2 then the cells of Table1 in rows 1 & 6 within Column4 would be highlighted.

Table1

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| asd | 1qa | abc | Yes | blah |
| qwe | 2ws | xyz | No | foo |
| zxc | 3ed | def | Yes | blah |
| qwe | 4rf | ghi | Yes | foo |
| asd | 2ws | ghi | Yes | blah |
| rty | 2ws | abc | No | foo |

Table2

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| asd | 1qa | abc | No |
| qwe | 2ws | xyz | No |
| asd | 2ws | ghi | Yes |
| rty | 2ws | abc | Yes |

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of the question, you can use Countifs (or Match if you prefer) but must [use Indirect for each table reference](https://superuser.com/questions/1517823/how-can-i-use-conditional-formatting-in-an-excel-table-using-structured-referenc):

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Table2[Column1]"),INDIRECT("Table1[@Column1]"),INDIRECT("Table2[Column2]"),INDIRECT("Table1[@Column2]"),INDIRECT("Table2[Column3]"),INDIRECT("Table1[@Column3]"))=0
```

[image]

Similarly the second part formula would be

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Table2[Column1]"),INDIRECT("Table1[@Column1]"),INDIRECT("Table2[Column2]"),INDIRECT("Table1[@Column2]"),INDIRECT("Table2[Column3]"),INDIRECT("Table1[@Column3]"),INDIRECT("Table2[Column4]"),"<>"&INDIRECT("Table1[@Column4]"))>0
```

[image]

**EDIT**

This is a bit tedious, but you can avoid the indirect by defining the structured references in the name manager (mentioned briefly [here](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1254922-proper-use-of-table-references-in-conditional-formatting.html))

e.g.

T1C1R2 is defined as

```
Table1[@Column1]
```

and T2C1 is defined as

```
Table2[Column1]
```

so the first formula becomes

```
=COUNTIFS(T2C1,T1C1R2,T2C2,T1C2R2,T2C3,T1C3R2)=0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since Indirect is a volatile function I'll try to use Match instead. I'm presuming I need to substitute these Indirect functions with a whole bunch of Index/Match functions or am I thinking about it wrong? This just messed me up today. No idea why.

Comment: As far as I know you would still have to use Indirect even with Match, but by all means give it a go.

Comment: There is another workaround for using structured references in CF which avoids indirect - have added it to my answer.

Comment: Excellent. I started doing that with the named ranges for the T2 columns, but hadn't for for the T1 row references so it makes sense why my next attempt was still  not working. It is tedious, but both my tables are quite large as well as other stuff so I don't want to risk any inefficiencies with volatile functions. I've already tripped over some performance pits that I've had to workaround to keep it useable.

Comment: Finally got a chance to try it and it worked great. Setting up the named ranges is tedious, but worth it for performance. Given the size of my data there was a very noticeable improvement using the named ranges over the Indirect function. One alteration was to change the first formula to =0 not >0 since I'm looking for records in Table1 that are NOT in Table2. If you edit this I'll flag your response as the answer.

Comment: Great! Yes I had it =0 in the sheet and the screen shot but it didn't get copied across correctly into the answer.